# Limit sending apps that can send my app an ACTION_SEND intent

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I know how to receive an `ACTION_SEND` intent with the `mime-type= text/plain`.

My problem is that I want to limit the sender apps that can send an intent to my app.

So, if I want to limit the sender app to Gmail, my app should appear in the chooser list only when the sender is Gmail and not any other app.

I want my app to appear in the chooser list only for Gmail and not for any other app.

Does there exist any `intent-filter` to achieve this in Android?

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry, there is no way to whitelist the apps you want to support (or, conversely, blacklist apps that you do not want to support).